# Any way to get the modified IDS from mongodb's bulk operations using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```js
let dbOperations = Edge.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
edges.forEach(edge => {
    dbOperations.find({_id: edge.id}).upsert().updateOne({
        $set: {
            value: edge.value
        },
        $setOnInsert: {
            _id: edge.id
        }
    })
})
dbOperations.execute()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.nModified) // This shows the number of edges that is actually modified
        console.log(result.getModifiedIds()) // This is what I want to achieve
    })
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you get an option to get modified IDs from response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well from one point of view the anwer is "no" and there is a very good reason for that.

Generally speaking, MongoDB "update" operations are intended to work across what is commonly "multiple" documents, therefore meaning whatever matched the criteria. So the general case here is whatever you either asked to be updated in either singular or by selection was either updated or not depending on whether anything was matched.

In the "Bulk" context, much of the same thing applies, in that there was either a criteria match or not, in which case you will get returned values for `nMatched` and `nModified` repectively, as there is also the possibility that a "matched" document is not actually updated where the data present to be modified is already the value which is the target of the modification.

That last distinction between `nMatched` and `nModified` is the prime reason why *"you cannot reliably do this"*, since not everything matched is necessarily modified.

You can however make a *guestimate* value in the case of discerning between "upsert" actions and actual "updates". It won't be 100% acurate because of the noted distintion, but the basic process is to compare your input list to the returned value from `getUpsertedIds()`, which is a valid call.

Eschewing the ES6 syntax for the rest of the world at present:

```js
var upserted = result.getUpsertedIds();    // get this from the bulk result

upserted = upserted.map(function(up) { return up._id }); // filter out just the _id values

var modifiedIds = edges.map(function(edge) {    // get _id only from source 
    return edge.id;  
}).filter(function(edge) {
    return upserted.indexOf(edge) == -1;        // and return only non upserted
});
```

Where the returned result of from `.getUpsertedIds()` is an array of objects containing both the "index" position from the bulk update and the generated or supplied `_id` value of the "upsert".

```js
[ { index: 0, _id: 1 } ]
```

So matching out your input list against the "upserted" list to see *"what is not there"*, basically returns things that where *probably* just modified. With of course the caveat that if the value was already the same as the modification, then it really was not a modification at all.

But due to how the API is meant to work, that's as close as you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. I guess there is no way of knowing (in bulk anyway) which documents that _actually got modified_, just that some did.

Comment: @Martol1ni That is the general caveat with `nModified` ( which is actually only ever correctly reported under the newer Bulk operations API anyway, as legacy API reported modified even if the same value ) that unless you are looking at one update at a time ( and one document ) it really is not an indicator of how many documents are affected as compared to `nMatched`. So if anything the number would be "over" reported, rather than "under"

Comment: @BlakesSeven I see your example is specific to upsert. Can you think of an alternative to return the Ids for a bulk  find().update() ?