# Is it possible to get back affected documents Ids with updateMany() in MongoDb NodeJs driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Right now this is what I get as response from `updateMany()`

**Response**

```
  [
{
    "result": {
        "n": 1,
        "nModified": 1,
        "opTime": {
            "ts": "6870210161760272385",
            "t": 23
        },
        "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000017",
        "ok": 1,
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": "6870210161760272385",
            "signature": {
                "hash": "nF2DFB6slcL/6QI/GSWOFC5i02I=",
                "keyId": "6808260988001845250"
            }
        },
        "operationTime": "6870210161760272385"
    },
    "connection": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 4,
        "id": 1,
        "address": "40.79.242.150:27017",
        "bson": {},
        "socketTimeout": 360000,
        "monitorCommands": false,
        "closed": false,
        "destroyed": false,
        "lastIsMasterMS": 209
    },
    "modifiedCount": 1,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 1,
    "n": 1,
    "nModified": 1,
    "opTime": {
        "ts": "6870210161760272385",
        "t": 23
    },
    "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000017",
    "ok": 1,
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6870210161760272385",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "nF2DFB6slcL/6QI/GSWOFC5i02I=",
            "keyId": "6808260988001845250"
        }
    },
    "operationTime": "6870210161760272385"
}
]
```

**This makes no sense to me at all. Except for the following few properties:**

```
"modifiedCount": 0,
"upsertedId": null,
"upsertedCount": 0,
"matchedCount": 1,
```

Can I get an array of all the ObjectIds or even entire document that have been affected as a result of 'updateMany()' in the response?

I know something similar is possible with `findOneAndUpdate()` but the catch is that it updates only a single record. I don't want to loop over it. That would be bad for performance.

Comment: `upsertedId` should contain updated _id, but you have zero documents modified or upserted. Can you show us a result where `upsertedCount` or `modifiedCount` is greater than 0?

Comment: I have updated it. Even though upsertedId is 0  modified count is greater an 0. Does it only happen when there is a upsert?

Comment: Yes, it is only for upsert, see doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#returns

Comment: For updated documents you already know the ids I think. You only get new (created) ids in `upsertedId`

Comment: @Anton how exactly do I "already know the ids" if I update like `db.col.updateMany({active: true}, {$inc:{cnt:1}})` ?

Comment: Problem is what if mongo DB updates only 50 of the 100 documents? And fails? How do I know how many have been updated and how many have failed . And which ones.

Comment: @SamuraiJack, you know **how many** have been updated from `modifiedCount` field of the response. If your update is idempotent  you can just repeat the query, you don't really need ids to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to get list of updated ids. Further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146212/any-way-to-get-the-modified-ids-from-mongodbs-bulk-operations-using-mongoose) (it is based on mongoose but you can extend the reasoning to MongoDb driver)
A second query to db should be required, perhaps using updated date field as filter if you know for sure your previous query was the last one (in the first query return you already know how many documents has been updated)