# Is there any option that returns newly updated or created document with full object instead of count in mongoose bulkWrite() method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

```
const operations = [
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { email: 'email.1@gmail.com' },
            update: {
                firstName: 'firstName.1',
                lastName: 'lastName.1',
                password: 'Password',
            },
            upsert: true,
        },
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { email: 'email.2@gmail.com' },
            update: {
                firstName: 'firstName.2',
                lastName: 'lastName.2',
                password: 'Password',
            },
            upsert: true,
        },
    },
    {
        updateOne: {
            filter: { email: 'email.3@gmail.com' },
            update: {
                firstName: 'firstName.3',
                lastName: 'lastName.3',
                password: 'Password',
            },
            upsert: true,
        },
    },
];
```

I have above operations that I want to perform inside bulkWrite operation.

```
try {
    const bulkWriteRes = await users.bulkWrite(operations);
    console.log(bulkWriteRes);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

But inside bulkWriteRes I;m getting only these details.

```
BulkWriteResult {
    ok: 1,
    writeErrors: [],
    writeConcernErrors: [],
    insertedIds: [],
    nInserted: 0,
    nUpserted: 1,
    nMatched: 3,
    nModified: 3,
    nRemoved: 0,
    upserted: [
        {
            index: 5,
            _id: '63c977188eb489a9c9cfa4e2',
        },
    ],
};
```

I want whole updated object whether it is created or update including filed _id, fields that I have passed in filter and update properties. Is there any options ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147669/9746258) will answer your question. AFAIK, what you're asking is not possible.