# MongoDB mongoose: how to bulk findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to upsert many records (about 1k-10k) on MongoDB via nodejs mongoose.

I need `_id` values of ALL upserted records, regardless of whether it was updated or inserted, because I have to use `_id` value to another schema (as a foreign key).

For single record, `findOneAndUpdate` method can be used, but it's not available in bulk operation or `bulkWrite` method.

Here is an quick summary of my project code.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

interface Item {
  name: string
  desc: string
  shop_ids?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[]
}

interface Shop {
  name: string
  items: {
    item_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    price: number
  }[]
}

const ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', new mongoose.Schema<Item>({
  name: String,
  desc: String,
  shop_ids: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
}))

const ShopModel = mongoose.model('Shop', new mongoose.Schema<Shop>({
  name: String,
  items: [{
    item_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    price: Number,
  }]
}))

interface ItemPrice {
  item: Item,
  price: number,
}

async function main() {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/trial')

  //  Clear existing records
  await ShopModel.deleteMany({})
  await ItemModel.deleteMany({})

  //  Sample existing records
  const shop1_itemprices: ItemPrice[] = [
    { item: { name: 'item1', desc: 'item1desc' }, price: 100 },
    { item: { name: 'item2', desc: 'item2desc' }, price: 200 },
    { item: { name: 'item3', desc: 'item3desc1' }, price: 300 },
  ]

  const shop1 = await (new ShopModel({ name: 'shop1' })).save()
  await applyShopItems(shop1, shop1_itemprices)


  const shop2_itemprices: ItemPrice[] = [
    { item: { name: 'item3', desc: 'item3desc1' }, price: 250 },
    { item: { name: 'item3', desc: 'item3desc2' }, price: 300 },
    { item: { name: 'item4', desc: 'item4desc' }, price: 200 },
  ]

  const shop2 = await (new ShopModel({ name: 'shop2' })).save()
  await applyShopItems(shop2, shop2_itemprices)

  await mongoose.disconnect()
}

type ShopDoc = mongoose.Document<unknown, any, Shop> & Shop & {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}

async function applyShopItems(shop: ShopDoc, item_prices: ItemPrice[]) {

  // //  Very ugly but simple example
  // for (const { item, price } of item_prices) {
  //   const item_doc = await ItemModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  //     { name: item.name, desc: item.desc },
  //     { $addToSet: { shop_ids: shop._id } },
  //     { upsert: true, new: true }
  //   )
  //   if (!item_doc) throw new Error('')
  //   shop.items.push({ item_id: item_doc._id, price })
  // }
  // await shop.save()

  //  What Really I want to do ...
  const bulk = ItemModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
  item_prices.map(({ item, price }) => {
    bulk.find({ name: item.name, desc: item.desc }).upsert().updateOne({
      $addToSet: { shop_ids: shop._id }
    })
  })

  const result = await bulk.execute()

  console.log('Upserted IDs:', result.getUpsertedIds()) //  OK
  //  console.log('Updated Ids:', result.getUpdatedIds()) // <--  Why not exists ???
  const item_ids: mongoose.Types.ObjectId[] = [/* ... */] //  <-- I want to get ALL ids (documents) on bulk operation here

  shop.items = item_ids.map((item_id, index) => ({ item_id, price: item_prices[index].price }))
  await shop.save()
}

main()
```

I made an ugly but simple implementation for this situation, with a simple `for` loop of `findOneAndUpdate` in the code above. But I'm concerned that this will cause peformance issues when processing 1k-10k records.

I checked a related question on [Any way to get the modified IDS from mongodb's bulk operations using mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146212/any-way-to-get-the-modified-ids-from-mongodbs-bulk-operations-using-mongoose) , but in my situation there are no `_id` values before doing upserts, so I couldn't use this question's answer.

Any other ways to achieve this?